# How to test .notify for .then in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred, angular-promise

In this post function

```
var deferredRespond = $q.defer();
            var statusNotice="Loading...";
            deferredRespond.notify(statusNotice);
$http.post(processorUrl,{
                params:request,
                }).success(function(respondData){
                        //deferredRespond.resolve(respondData);
                        /*For Test Rejected Defer! -awh*/
                        deferredRespond.resolve($q.reject("Simulated Reject"));
                        //deferredRespond.resolve($q.notify("Simulated LOADING..."));
                    })
                    .error(function(){
                        deferredRespond.reject('Failed defer!');
                    });
```

I am able to simulate .reject by doing `.resolve($q.reject` But I wonder why I can not test the .notify by doing `.resolve($q.notify` (it will return error of undefined)? Is there some other way I can test the .notify?

Thank You

Comment: You don't need to do that at all; `post()` already returns a promise.

Comment: @SLaks I updated the function above, so, thats what I have done for the notify, but seems its not relaly print out for the .then in the controller.

Comment: $q.resolve() and $q.reject() return promises (resolved or rejected), it seems that notify doesn't return promise.

Comment: @freele Thanks for the comment! Is there way to test .notify though? I am pretty confused how it works and can't really find a targetted material to study on

Comment: @Chen What about q docs and sources https://github.com/kriskowal/q ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notify callback is the part of `then` syntax and can be used to provide a status of the process flow.

If you want to notify you should not use `deferredRespond.resolve` with `$q`, you just need to call notify method directly of the deferred object:

```
deferredRespond.notify('Simulated LOADING...');
```

And you will be able to subscribe to all three situations using `then`:

```
deferredRespond.promise.then(function(data) {
    console.log('resolved', data);
}, 
function(data) {
    console.log('rejected', data);
}, 
function(data) {
    console.log('notified', data);
});
```

Note that the first callback function in `then` corresponds to resolutions, the second to rejections, and the third is for notifications send with `deferredRespond.notify`.